# How can I apply function using stackApply or Calc, in rasterEngine, and save the results as raster object in R? # edited

Tags: r, r-raster, getvalue

I have been working in a list of function to process MODIS vegetation index timeseries and return crop cycle paramenters. It's for PhD thesis and I'll process all South America, so I need to use all forms to reduce the time to process.

I found the rasterEngine from the spatial.tools package to use paralell processing to speed up the process. but, before that I prepare some of the functions to compute by pixel over the raster stack my variables measures.

I develop the functions which will produce 7 different outputs, I tried tu use my function "CropAnalysis" to compute by each pixel, in the code in the post I try to save a raster brick with 2 layers (each one with one of variables produced by the function "CropAnalysis").

I edited the code, but couldn't solve the problem when I run the process.

Attached are the data (one small portion of data) and the code, any idea?

My data:
Modis stack https://www.dropbox.com/s/uesgzv125e3v3e6/stackimagesNDVI.tif?dl=0

My code:

```
library(stringr)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)


# loading the data 
limit <- 3000 # minimum value betweem maximum and minimum to be crop
ndates <- 2 # time difference between maximum and minimum to be crop
min_diff <- 3000 # threshold for the maximum value (this is the minimum value to test)
min_val <- 1500 # minimum value for the minimum pixel values be trustfull (threshold)
max_phase_duration <- 7  # the maximum interval over the maximum value between the two adjacent minimum values
number_of_crop_cycles <- 3  # definition of number of crop cycles per croo year

imgStacked <- brick('stackimagesNDVI.tif')

CropAnalysis <- function (pixel, ...){
   pixel <- as.vector(pixel)

   # test : if is No data the return is 
   if (is.na(pixel)) {-1}
     else{

     # delta (valor i - valor i+1)
     delta <- pixel[2:length(pixel)] - pixel[1:(length(pixel)-1)]

     # maximum and minimum point
     ptma<-NULL
     ptmi <- NULL

     # verifing why the first time point is not signed???? T or F
     if (pixel[2] > pixel [1]) {ptmi <- 1}
     if (pixel[2] < pixel [1]) {ptma <- 1}

     # computing the slope of the line change from positive to negative 
     for (j in 1:(length(delta)-1))
     {
     if (delta[j]>0 && delta[j+1]<0 )
     {
      ptma<- c(ptma,j+1)   # point of maximum
     }

     if (delta[j]<0 && delta[j+1]>0)
    {
     ptmi<- c(ptmi,j+1)   # point of minimum
    }
   }
   # verifing why the first time point is not signed???? T or F
   if (pixel[(length(pixel))] > pixel [(length(pixel)-1)])  {ptma <- c(ptma,length(pixel))} 
   if (pixel[(length(pixel))] < pixel [(length(pixel)-1)])  {ptmi <- c(ptmi,length(pixel))}

   # variables for save the measures for crop cycle
   max_points <- as.numeric(rep(0, number_of_crop_cycles))  # number of maximum peaks after test if is a crop pixel
   length_max_period <- as.numeric(rep(NA, number_of_crop_cycles))  # variation of number of dates between the minimum points around of maximum point 
   max_valids <- NULL

   # agricultural detection 
   for (j in 1:length(ptma))
   {
    index <- ptma[j]
    # logical tests to verify the presence of crop
    # from each maximum value, check if:
    # 1st - the maximum position had the before minimum value far or equal than "ndatas" variable
    # 2nd - the maximum position had the after minimum value far or equal than ndatas variable
    # 3th - the value of maximum is equal or great than "val_min" variable (threshold)
    # 4th - the difference between the maximum value and the two minimum values (in the "ndates") distance is equal or bigher than "limit" variable (threshold value of increase Vegetation index)
    # 5th - the minimum values bigher tha minimum limit variable 
    # 6th - check to exclude sugarcane from anual crop cicle 
    if(!is.na(((ptmi[ptmi < index][length(ptmi[ptmi < index])]+ndates) <= index  && # 1st test
      index <= (ptmi[ptmi > index][1]-ndates)) && # 2sd test
     (pixel[index] >= limit) && # 3th test
     ((pixel[index]-pixel[ptmi[ptmi < index]][length(pixel[ptmi[ptmi < index]])] >= min_diff) && (pixel[index]-pixel[ptmi[ptmi > index]][1] > min_diff)) && # 4th test
     (pixel[ptmi[ptmi < index]][length(pixel[ptmi[ptmi < index]])] && pixel[ptmi[ptmi > index]][1] >= min_val) && # 5th
     ((ptmi[ptmi < index][length(ptmi[ptmi < index])] <= index-(max_phase_duration-3) && index-(max_phase_duration-3)>= 1) |  (ptmi[ptmi > index][1] >= index+(max_phase_duration-3))))) # 6th
     {
      # computing the valid maximum values to avoid the "fake" crop pattern (small difference between min and max) and using this "position_data" to save the values in the vectors in the right order
      max_valids <- c(max_valids, index)
      position_data <- which(max_valids==index)
      # saving the points of maximum per pixel over the time series
      max_points[position_data] <- index

      # calculating the crop cycle length
      length_max_period[position_data] <- (index-ptmi[ptmi < index][length(ptmi[ptmi < index])])+(ptmi[ptmi > index][1]-index)
      }

     }
    # replacing the NA data (NA is the default value and show possible cropseasons whitout crops)
     #max_points[is.na(max_points)]<-0

     # join the values in a unique number: i.e = c(5,16, 0) -> 99051600 ( 99 = to avoid the difference of length of pixel value in cases of numbers lower than 10; all valid number using flag 0)
     max_points <- as.integer(paste('99',paste(formatC(max_points, flag=0, digits = 1,format = 'd'),collapse = ''),sep=""))

     length_max_period <- as.integer(paste('99',paste(formatC(length_max_period, flag=0, digits = 1,format = 'd'),collapse = '')),sep="")

      }
    }
```

.
        # using stackApply

```
    data_process <- stackApply(imgStacked, indices=c(rep(1,nlayers(imgStacked)),rep(2,nlayers(imgStacked))), fun=CropAnalysis)
```

The error message:

Error in length_max_period[position_data] <- (index - ptmi[ptmi < index [length(ptmi[ptmi <  : replacement has length zero

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In stackApply(imgStacked, indices = c(rep(1, nlayers(imgStacked)),  : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

2: In if (is.na(pixel)) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

```
    # using calc
    data_process<-calc(x=imgStacked, fun=CropAnalysis, forcefun=TRUE, forceapply=TRUE)
```

The error message:

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "layer") : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In if (is.na(pixel)) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

2: In if (is.na(pixel)) { :the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

3: In fun(tstdat) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

4: In fun(tstdat) : NAs introduced by coercion

5: In if (is.na(pixel)) { :the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

6: In fun(x) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

7: In fun(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

8: In matrix(values, nrow = ncell(x), ncol = nlayers(x)) : data length exceeds size of matrix

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error message? If so, provide the message in the question. You really should provide the smallest amount of code necessary to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick I edited the code, is working for 1 output, but because of the size of analysis to be done, and the number of variables to get I need to apply once time and return 7 differente layers (each one form on variable, for example, "max_points" and "length_max_period" shown in the code).